# WinForm update installer - dynamically set installation directory

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer, desktop-application

I have little problem which I didn't find solution on. I have done Windows form application with msi installer made via setup wizard. Everything works fine except one thing. This application is connected to server with update installers, so when new update is available it downloads the installer and runs it. But when the update installation starts you need to select installation directory again. Which means if you forget about it your old settings will not be loaded from older version and this is big problem.

So I need to pass my application directory to the installer when starting the update.

Can anyone help me, please? I don't have almost any experience with installers, so be aware of that, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is usually solved at design time by having the settings in a folder that doesn't change, such as CommonApplicationData. Is it too late to do this?

Comment: Yes, for this is to late. The main problem is that there can be installed multiple instances of this application on one server in multiple directories.It's because of what the customer wanted, so he needs to change the folder as he needs... :/